# Are UnsamQ and Not[SameQ] the same function?

Tags: functions, function-construction, expression-test

Why are the following functions

```
a[x___] := If[ UnsameQ[x, Null],    1, 2, 3]
b[x___] := If[ Not[SameQ[x, Null]], 1, 2, 3]
```

different? For example

```
a[]
(*1*)
a[1]
(*1*)
b[]
(*2*)
b[1]
(*1*)
```

In particular, why does `a[]` gives `1` instead of `2`?

I didn't expect that also because

```
UnsameQ[x, y] == Not[SameQ[x, y]]
UnsameQ[x, Null] == Not[SameQ[x, Null]]
(*True*)
(*True*)
```

Moreover, if I define

```
uns[a_, b_] := UnsameQ[a, b]
nts[a_, b_] := Not[SameQ[a, b]]
```

the functions

```
c[x___] := If[nts[x, Null], 1, 2, 3]
d[x___] := If[uns[x, Null], 1, 2, 3]
```

are different from the previous ones:

```
c[]
(*3*)
c[1]
(*1*)
d[]
(*3*)
d[1]
(*1*)
```

Why does it happens?

The same question holds for `SameQ` and `Not[UnsameQ]`

Comment: You're actually evaluating `UnsameQ[Null]` and `SameQ[Null]` both of which return `True`. The `BlankNullSequence` spits out something akin to `Sequence[]` if you have no match.

Comment: One is the negation of the other *with two arguments only*.  They take any number of arguments.  When used with fewer or more arguments, the identity does not hold. Another example would be `SameQ[a, b, a]` and `UnsameQ[a, b, a]`, which are both false, as these expressions are neither all identical, nor all different.

Comment: The behaviour of SameQ is weird if there is only one parameter. SameQ[x] == True. According to the documentation, "lhs===rhs
yields True if the expression lhs is identical to rhs, and yields False otherwise. " If there is no rhs, SameQ should return False, however it doesn't.

Comment: This is far from trivial. Voting "leave open".

Comment: @UnchartedWorks from the docs, `e1===e2===e3` gives `True` if all the `ei` are identical. (equivalent to `SameQ[e1,e2,e3]`. *Of course* in a set of just `[e1]` all of the `ei` are identical. No reason to return `False`.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP How about UnsameQ[x]? It gives True.

Comment: @UnchartedWorks similarly, there is not a single pair of arguments that match there :-)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP UnsameQ yields True if the expression lhs is not identical to rhs, and yields False otherwise. Should UnsameQ give False? ;)

Comment: @UnchartedWorks see Details section: `UnsameQ[e1,e2,e3]` is true if no two `ei` are identical. There are no two `ei` in `UnsameQ[e1]` so no two `ei` are identical.

Comment: @ LLlAMnYP "the expression lhs is not identical to rhs" is not equivalent to "no two ei are identical". It's confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to assume that `a[]` and `b[]` are the same as `a[Null]` and `b[Null]`, but they are not. If you were to run a `Trace` on `a[]` and `b[]`, you would see

```
Trace[a[]]
```

> `{a[], 
>   If[UnsameQ[Null], 1, 2, 3], 
>   {UnsameQ[Null], True}, If[True, 1, 2, 3], 1}`

```
Trace[b[]]
```

> `{b[], 
>   If[!SameQ[Null], 1, 2, 3], 
>   {{SameQ[Null], True}, !True, False}, If[False, 1, 2, 3], 2}`

Both `UnsameQ` and `SameQ` are only seeing one argument, which is an edge case not discussed in the Mathematica documentation (), but the traces show how of these functions behave differently when given a single argument, explaining the differences you are seeing.

Comment: An illustration: `f[x___] := HoldComplete@x; f[]` returns `HoldComplete[]`.

Comment: That's is interesting: so let's say that if I have a function `f[a_,b___]` and I want that if I input only one argument I get `f[a]=a` but if I input 2 arguments I get `f[a,b]=2a+b`. How can I implement that?

Comment: @Giancarlo. Please don't ask a new question in a comment. However, in the case you bring up in your comment, I would suggest `f[x_] := x; f[x_, y_] := 2 x + y`

Comment: Thanks m_goldberg. Related to the original question, it's still not clear to me why `a[]` is different from `d[]`, and, similarly, `b[]` is different from `c[]`. Do you have any idea why?