# Optional argument as a correction of a main argument

Tags: function-construction

Let's consider a function

```
f[a_,b___]
```

I want that if I input only one argument I get

```
f[a]=a
```

but if I input 2 arguments I get

```
 f[a,b]=2a+b
```

How can I implement that?

I thought I could use `If`:

```
f[a_,b___]:=If[b===Null,a,2a+b]
```

but reading this previous post [Are UnsamQ and Not[SameQ] the same function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147280/are-unsamq-and-notsameq-the-same-function) I think it's not the correct way.

I could use 2 different definition for `f[a_]` and `f[a_,b_]` but I'd like to have only one definition. In fact, my problem arises because if `f` has only one argument, `f` performs analytic calculation, but with two argument (where the second argument is a "correction" of the first one) `f` needs, in only one part, a numerical calculations; anyway the computation that `f` performs is the same in both cases.

Comment: You should use two definitions, `f[a_] := a; f[a_, b__] := 2a+b`.  In your code, you could use `MatchQ[Hold[b], Hold[]]` for the condition test.  (You could also use `SameQ` instead of `MatchQ`.)

Comment: I agree with previous comment that the simplest way would be to just use two definitions. One more alternative to make do with one could be `f[x__] := If[Length[{x}] == 1, First[{x}], 2 First[{x}] + Last[{x}]]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two definitions, as recommended by m_goldberg and Michael E2, really is the preferred solution:

```
f[a_]     := a
f[a_, b_] := 2 a + b
```

This is both clear and efficient.

If you prefer an `If` statement then perhaps:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[a_, b___] := If[Hold[b] === Hold[], a, 2 a + b]
```

I am using [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) for generality, as in some cases one would not wish for the arguments to evaluate.  That may not matter if `f` does not itself have a hold attribute but I felt it better to illustrate this than to omit it.

If you want to be clever we can exploit the specific definition of the example and write:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[a_: 0, b_] := 2 a + b

f[x]
f[x, y]
```

> ```
> x
>
> 2 x + y
> ```

This works by making parameter `a` [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) with a default value of zero.  When it is not provided the term `2 a` therefore vanishes from the sum.  If this kind of trickery pleases you see also what I call ["vanishing patterns."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44084/121)

Comment: My original problem is that I have a function `f` that is quite complex. In only one part it needs to solve a system of equations. The system can be very complex, depending on the terms in his argument `a`. So my idea was to put simple terms in the first argument and complex terms in the second one. So if there are complex terms (2nd argument), `f` uses `FindRoot` otherwise (when the 2nd argument is absent) `Solve`; but, apart from this choice `FindRoot`-`Solve` all the rest is exactly the same. This is why I was looking for only one function instead than a function and his "copy".

Comment: So, also in this case, would you suggest to have 2 different functions?

Comment: @Giancarlo I would need to see the function(s) to give my best recommendation.  Probably I would use two definitions but one of them would hand off to the other, passing `FindRoot` or `Solve` as a parameter perhaps.

Comment: Well, in my specific case I' ll use the `If` in this way `f[a_, b_:0] := If[b==0,a (*that means using Solve in my case*), 2a+b (*that means using FindRoot in my case*)]`. Thank you :)

Comment: sorry, with `===` instead of `==`, that means `f[a_, b_:0] := If[b===0,a , 2a+b]`

Comment: @Giancarlo I take it you do not wish to post your full function code for review?